# Abbreviations do not work when space is conditionally remapped

Tags: abbreviations

I want to change the behavior of `<Space>` when the popup menu is open using this map

`inoremap <expr> <Space> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>\<Enter>" : "\<Space>"`

However, with this map my abbreviations no longer get triggered when terminated by a `<Space>`.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: Make it return `C-]` in insert mode before the space

Comment: Christian, that should be an answer, not a comment.